# Vertical volume slider with jMediaelement

Tags: jquery, html, html5-audio

I am using jMediaelement for a customized HTML5 audio player. Unfortunately, client now needs a vertical volume slider.

When calling the jMediaelement API, I can only use this markup:

```
 <div class="volume-slider" title="volume slider"></div>
```

...which will be replaced by a horizontal volume slider.
How can I adjust the volume handle to be vertical (from bottom=silent to top=loud)?

[image: Screenshot of my player]

PS: I already opened an [issue at Sourceforge](https://github.com/aFarkas/jMediaelement/issues/26), however, no answer yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, Alexander [replied](https://github.com/aFarkas/jMediaelement/issues/26#issuecomment-11157593) to the question himself. 
Here's his working solution:

> It's quite simple. JME uses jQuery-UI slider and jQuery-UI
>   **automatically detects** wether you want a vertical or horizontal slider
>   by your CSS. The only thing you have to do is to give your slider a
>   bigger height than a bigger width.
>
> The following css would create a vertical slider:
>
> ```
> .volume-slider {
>     height: 300px;
>     width: 20px;
> }
> ```
>
> If this doesn't help, you can pass a vertical option to the slider.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the jMediaelement API, but you could use css to rotate the volume 90 degrees counter-clockwise. You'll probably have to mess with the event handlers to get the volume handle to track vertical movement instead of horizontal, but that shouldn't be to hard.

Here's an article on rotating with CSS

http://davidwalsh.name/css-transform-rotate

Comment: To be honest, rotating an element with CSS3 seems to create more problems than it solves. What about outdated browsers, starting with IE8?

Comment: that's addressed in the article I posted, you can accomplish it with IE's filters. Seems like the other answer is a whole lot easier though.